# PHPmailer stopped working locally after updating MAMP to version 6.4

Tags: phpmailer, mamp

As the title said, after updating MAMP to version 6.4 I get the error "SMTP connect() failed" when I try to send an email using phpmailer. I uploaded the files to the live server to check and it works fine,  problem is MAMP. Any idea how to fix it?